# Echo behaving strangely, out of order output

Tags: variables, echo

I can't wrap my head around what could possibly be happening here. I'm writing a script to remediate the recent log4j vulnerability but I'm hitting a wall right at the get-go:

```
#!/bin/bash

JarFile="$1"
echo testing $JarFile version: 
unzip -p $1 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Log4jReleaseVersion
JV=$(unzip -p $JarFile META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Log4jReleaseVersion | awk '{print $2}')
echo ${JV}
JMaj=$(echo $JV | cut -d . -f1)
JMin=$(echo $JV | cut -d . -f2)

echo Major: $JMaj
echo Minor: $JMin

echo Major version is $JMaj and Minor is $JMin Randomtext here
```

and here's the output:

```
% ./Remed.sh /var/mqsi/shared-classes/log4j-api-2.5.jar
testing /var/mqsi/shared-classes/log4j-api-2.5.jar version:
Log4jReleaseVersion: 2.5
2.5
Major: 2
Minor: 5
 Randomtext here 2 and Minor is 5
```

Why is that last echo command all out of whack? I boiled the script down to this because whatever is happening here is breaking everything downstream. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Could there be a carriage return character being printed, so that ` Random text here` gets printed at the start of the line?

Comment: That seems to be the case - very strange since I'm just assigning the output of a command to variables. Is unzip introducing strange characters?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. For others banging their heads against the wall, it's an encoding (CRLF) issue apparently introduced by unzip. dos2unix fixed it; not sure if there's a more elegant way but here's what did it:

```
JV=$(unzip -p $JarFile META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Log4jReleaseVersion | awk '{print $2}') 
JMaj=$(echo $JV | cut -d . -f1 | dos2unix) 
JMin=$(echo $JV | cut -d . -f2 | dos2unix)
```